# How can I install Siberian CMS to Azure? problems during entering database information

Tags: azure, content-management-system, azure-sql-database, siberiancms

Help with installation would be appreciated. Already succeeded installing to GoDaddy servers but now when trying to install to Azure (as web app) I constantly receive error while entering database information during installation process. My Azure setup runs on Apache and PHP 7.0.32. Error is caused by mixed content:

(jquery.js?1541940728:5 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.example.com/installer/installation_database/check'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.).

I have read basically every info what I was able to find and only relevant hint was to install from http.
Does anyone have experience from installing Siberian CMS to Azure and Are you able to help with this?

Thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwLWc.png)

Comment: Azure SQL Database is not supported by Siberian CMS. It works only with MySQL, On the software documentation and the Siberian CMS community forum does not exist any reference to any of the top cloud services providers. They recommend 2 VPS provders. https://doc.siberiancms.com/knowledge-base/siberian-server-requirements/

Comment: Thanks, pretty obvious and should have crossed my mind. Nevertheless, Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You are welcome. I posted my comments as answer to make if more easy to read for other users in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database is not supported by Siberian CMS. It works only with MySQL.

Siberian CMS recommends VPS options provided by OVH and Contabo as explained on [this](https://doc.siberiancms.com/knowledge-base/siberian-server-requirements/) documentation.